How can I persistently cache Config and associated data for retrieval across service restarts?
I am working on a distributed library where I have a dynamically-generated Config class that initializes attributes from keyword arguments, as shown below:
from typing import TypeVar, Any

Serializable = TypeVar('Serializable', int, float, str, bool, list, set, dict)

def _init(self, **kwargs: dict[str, Serializable]) -> None:
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)

def _repr(self) -> str:
    return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({", ".join([f"{key}={value}" for key, value in vars(self).items()])})'

Config = type('Config', 
              (object,), 
              {'__init__': _init, 
               '__repr__': _repr, 
               'to_dict': lambda self: vars(self)})

I have a get_data function that fetches data based on the Config parameters. If the data is not available, it queries an SQL database:
def get_data(config: Config) -> Any:
    data: Any = ...  # get data from config
    if data is None:
        # search SQL database using config parameters
        ...
    return data

Problem
I need to cache the Config and the corresponding data in such a way that the data can be retrieved even after restarting the service. Using an in-memory cache like lru_cache does not persist data across restarts, so it's not suitable for this requirement.
Requirements:

Persistent Caching: The cache should persist data to disk or another form of long-term storage.
Retrieval Efficiency: The cache should allow for efficient retrieval of data based on Config parameters.
Support for Complex Keys: The caching mechanism should support complex objects as keys. for example the user may provide multiple item retrieval but the caching solution should cache them one at a time (unless there is a better solution) to prevent multiple searches if the same item is requested twice in different sets of items.

Questions:

What are some recommended approaches or libraries for persistently caching data in Python that fit this use case?
How can I serialize and store Config objects and ensure they can be deserialized for cache lookups after a service restart?
Are there any specific considerations or pitfalls I should be aware of when implementing persistent caching in a distributed system?

PS: I am not looking for code implementation. Just guidance on good practices / considerations before implementations. Thank you.
